# Jetpack Navigation: Any fragment should be able to navigate to any fragment

Tags: android, kotlin, android-fragments, android-jetpack-navigation

I have a game flow where the user goes through 6 `fragments` in a row. Now some complexity has been added. It is possible that each `fragment` can be reached by each `fragment`. It depends on what the players answer...

The good thing is, no backstack is needed. I.e. once I am in a `fragment`, I can't go back.

Anyway, I could now connect any `fragment` to any `fragment` in the `nav_graph` by `xml` with `<action>`. However, this makes my `nav_graph` very cluttered and I have a lot of redundant navigation code. Additionally, this solution scales very difficult. What do I do if I suddenly have 10 `fragments`?

What I want to write a function like `goToNextFragment`, which could be located in the associated `Activity` for example. So if needed, each `fragment` can call `activity.goToNextFragment()` and the navigation will be executed accordingly. Unfortunately, I can't find an approach to do this. I could of course initialize the new `fragment` on the `nav_graph` as `host`. But this seems strange to me and will probably break the transition.

Does anyone have an idea that could help me?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think global actions can help solve your problem.
You can put them on the same level as the fragments in the navigation graph.
At least the navigation graph would be less cluttered

**Example:**

```xml
<navigation xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    
    <fragment
        android:id="@+id/coolFragment"
     ...
    />
     
    <action
        android:id="@+id/coolFragmentAction"
        app:destination="@id/coolFragment" />
</navigation>
```

You can read more about it here:
https://developer.android.com/guide/navigation/navigation-global-action

Comment: A follow-up question, can't we just add all the fragments in the nav graph and navigate by just using their id? If so we don't have to define any actions right? or am I missing something?